# I try to use select union with order by and now i can select it but it seem like it not order by date with what i expect why?

Tags: mysql, select, order-by, union

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT sale.NAME AS "Name"
        ,sale.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,sale.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,sale.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,sale.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,sale.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,sale.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabsales_action` sale
    WHERE sale.workflow_state = 'Done'
    ORDER BY sale.close_date DESC
    ) `tabsales_action`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT mfi.NAME AS "Name"
        ,mfi.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,mfi.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,mfi.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,mfi.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,mfi.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,mfi.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabmfi_loan_action` mfi
    WHERE mfi.workflow_state = 'Done'
    ORDER BY mfi.close_date DESC
    ) `tabmfi_loan_action`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT credit.NAME AS "Name"
        ,credit.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,credit.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,credit.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,credit.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,credit.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,credit.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabin_house_credit_action` credit
    WHERE credit.workflow_state = 'Done'
    ORDER BY credit.close_date DESC
    ) `tabin_house_credit_action`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT service.NAME AS "Name"
        ,service.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,service.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,service.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,service.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,service.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,service.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabservices_planning` service
    WHERE service.workflow_state = 'Done'
    ORDER BY service.close_date DESC
    ) `tabservices_planning`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT account.NAME AS "Name"
        ,account.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,account.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,account.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,account.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,account.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,account.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabaccounting_action` account
    WHERE account.workflow_state = 'Done'
    ORDER BY account.close_date DESC
    ) `tabaccounting_action`
```

Comment: Why is the 5 different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are sorting by `close_date` column in all the tables in `DESC` order then `UNION`. Instead of this approach `SELECT UNION` all the tables and, in the final result you can `ORDER BY` the `Close Date:data:200` as `DESC`.

The working query will be:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
    SELECT sale.NAME AS "Name"
        ,sale.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,sale.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,sale.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,sale.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,sale.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,sale.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabsales_action` sale
    WHERE sale.workflow_state = 'Done'

    UNION

    SELECT mfi.NAME AS "Name"
        ,mfi.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,mfi.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,mfi.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,mfi.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,mfi.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,mfi.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabmfi_loan_action` mfi
    WHERE mfi.workflow_state = 'Done'

    UNION

    SELECT credit.NAME AS "Name"
        ,credit.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,credit.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,credit.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,credit.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,credit.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,credit.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabin_house_credit_action` credit
    WHERE credit.workflow_state = 'Done'

    UNION

    SELECT service.NAME AS "Name"
        ,service.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,service.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,service.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,service.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,service.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,service.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabservices_planning` service
    WHERE service.workflow_state = 'Done'

    UNION

    SELECT account.NAME AS "Name"
        ,account.responsible AS "Responsible:data:200"
        ,account.action_type AS "Action Type:data:200"
        ,account.id_customer AS "Id_Customer"
        ,account.workflow_state AS "Workflow:data:200"
        ,account.close_date AS "Close Date:data:200"
        ,account.modified_by AS "Done By:data:200"
    FROM `tabaccounting_action` account
    WHERE account.workflow_state = 'Done'
) AS T
ORDER BY T.`Close Date:data:200` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer `SELECT * FROM` does not have to respect the `ORDER BY` in the inner query.

Other RDBMSes will actually error in this situation, as an `ORDER BY` in subqueries is deemed invalid/not necessary.

To fix, alter your query so it's of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT sale.name as "Name",
-- rest of subquery
ORDER BY account.close_date desc) tabaccounting_action
ORDER BY "Close Date:data:200" DESC
```

Oh, and also the `UNIONS` affect the situation - I missed them because the question was formatted like someone had been sick on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra layer `SELECT * FROM (...)`, do this

```
( SELECT ... ) -- without any ORDER BY
UNION
( SELECT ... ) -- without any ORDER BY
UNION
...
UNION
( SELECT ... ) -- without any ORDER BY
ORDER BY ...
```

Because of the parentheses, it is clear that the `ORDER BY` belongs to the result of the `UNION`, not the final `SELECT`.

It is usually 'wrong' to have multiple tables with the same schema.  Consider combining those tables into one, perhaps with an extra column to say which it is.  Then you can get rid of the `UNIONs`.